# Can promises be used in JavaScript if I want to do something after the .then() fires

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
async function fetchUserCollection(callback)
{
    await client.connect();

    const userCollection = client.db('database').collection('users');
    await callback(userCollection);

    client.close();
}
```

I'm trying to move away from callbacks and towards Promises.

However `await resolve(userCollection)` would not work here if this was a promise as `resolve()` returns immediately.

Is there a way to use promises here? or is a callback necessary here?

Comment: What sort of thing does `.collection` return? How's it intended to be used?

Comment: Or, does your current code work, but you want to avoid the `callback` part of it and have the consumer use the returned Promise instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's a mongodb collection, but it could be any variable that will become out of scope after `client.close()` is called. It's more of a general JavaScript query. My current code works I want to avoid the callback element

Comment: So, do you just want this: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784)

Comment: @VLAZ No because I want to do stuff inside of my API after calling my callback which none of the answers in there seem to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a plain Promise won't work here, because a plain Promise is mostly indifferent to the `.then`s that may be called on it later. All that a Promise can do with `.then`s called on it is to execute them once the Promise resolves, and that's **it**. Spec-compliant Promises don't have a functionality to run something *after* something finishes consuming them with `.then`.

I think what you're doing currently is the cleanest solution there is. Despite the fact that Promises exist, callbacks aren't inherently bad - sometimes there are use cases for them, like here. The main issue with callbacks IMO is when they get nested in each other, and a lot of ugly indentation and hard-to-read code results, but that's not going on in your code.